# Processing data with different number of features

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, pandas

I have this classification/regression task but the most interesting thing is that the number of features for each record is different. Features are already extracted and already prepared thus the context of the data is unknown, and the values of the features fluctuate from -10 to 10. There are records with more than 200 features, likewise there are records with the amount of features lower than 20.

The dataframe `df` has two columns: `ID` and `ATTRIBUTES`and the output looks like this:

```
      ID                                          ATTRIBUTES                
   0  1  1.1 2.1 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 ... 99.9  100.0 101.1 102.2
   1  2  1.1 2.1 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 ... 45.0  46.0  47.0  49.0 
   2  3  1.1 2.1 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 ... 9.0   10.0  11.0  12.0
   3  4  1.1 2.1 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 ... 70.0  71.0  72.0  73.0
   4  5  1.1 2.1 3.3 4.4 5.5 6.6 ... 131.0 132.0 134.0 135.0
```

I have split column `ATTRIBUTES` into separate columns:

`df['ATTRIBUTES'].str.split(' ', expand=True).astype(float)`

Now `df` looks like this:

```
       0   1    2   3   4    5    6    7    8   9  ...   131   132   133   134   135 
       0  1.1  2.1 3.3 4.4. 5.5. 6.6. 7.7  8.8 9.9 ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN 
       1  1.1  2.1 3.3 4.4. 5.5. 6.6. 7.7  8.8 9.9 ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
       2  1.1  2.1 3.3 4.4. 5.5. 6.6. 7.7  8.8 9.9 ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
       3  1.1  2.1 3.3 4.4. 5.5. 6.6. 7.7  8.8 9.9 ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
       4  1.1  2.1 3.3 4.4. 5.5. 6.6. 7.7  8.8 9.9 ...  131.0 132.0 133.0 134.0 135.0
```

Let's say record1 has 102 features, rec2 - 49, rec3- 12, rec4-73, rec5 - 135. After a split operation records `rec1, rec2, rec3, rec4` were populated with `NaN` values to fill dataframe.

The label (`answer`) column is a single column of real values (float) which variate from -10 to 10:

```
 >>> answer
 0   8.8
 1  -5.3
 2   8.8
 3   5.4
 4   9.7
```

I’ve used LabelEncoder() to label `answer` column:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
lbl_Encoder = LabelEncoder()
lbl_Encoder.fit(answer)
answer_labeled = lbl_Encoder.transform(answer)

>>> answer_labeled
array([1, 2, 1, 3, 4])
```

After some googling I've came up with following ideas:

1. First thought was to change `NaN` values with meaningful features using 
   [Imputer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html);
2. Discard records that have less than 20 (40, 60 etc.) features.

For classification I had chosen RandomForest.

The baseline performance is approximately 0.4117 whilst validating 10% of training set (using scikit's train_test_split).

Despite everything I had tried:

1. [Feature scaling - standardisation](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html)
2. Dimensionality reduction via Principal Component Analysis (PCA)
3. Tree-based feature selection using

For baseline performance I used following:

```
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier
clf_dummy = DummyClassifier(strategy='most_frequent',random_state=SEED)
clf_dummy.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf_dummy.score(X_test, y_test)

>>> clf_dummy.score(X_test, y_test)
0.33062330623306235
```

The performance of RandomForest scored approximately 0.4. I have tried to apply various configurations to RF, but the score has not been improved, therefore additional data processing should be applied, probably.

So my question is - how would one should proceed with the lack of features for particular records?

Comment: You could either only use the features which all records share or you can train several classifiers for subgroups of features.

Comment: The thing is I don't know which particular feature may correspond to same property across the records. But the idea of usage of several classifiers is great. Thank you for that.

Comment: Check the sklearn documentation on missing values : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#imputation-of-missing-values